# use 8 ball to clear pocket

Tags: rules, pool

Two balls on table. Opponents ball blocking pocket and 8 ball used to sink opponents ball to clear pocket and then sink the 8 ball behind it in the same shot. Is this a legal shot?

Comment: Could you please specify the exact set of rules you're following? Pool rules do differ between the different rule sets, and without knowing the exact rules nobody's going to be able to give you an answer.